# Bootstrap container not position properly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap to style my website. However it doesn't work perfectly as I think.

**Below is my code:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    float: left;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444;
    width: 100%;
    background: white;

}
```

As you see at below image, the right-most gap is wider than the left-most gap. Anyone has idea?

[image]

Comment: What's the CSS for `.box` ?

Comment: my box css: .box { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.4em; float: left; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444; width: 100%; background: white; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

That follows the opening of the open container.
Code below:

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="span6">
          <div class="box"></div>
       </div>
     <div class="span6">
        <div class="box"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

if that doesnt work, post the css for box or give a URL so I can examine the css computed style

Comment: It is the same. my box css: .box {
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 11px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 float: left;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #444;
 width: 100%;
 background: white;

}

Comment: Can I get the url for the page ?

Comment: You are right! I think the margin of box exceeds the row, I solved it by making it 0px.